# Inverse hyperoperation code library

Tags: hyperoperation

I hope you're having a nice day,
I am an Electrical Engineer and I am trying to do a math paper, but I need a coding library in any coding language that can do inverse hyperoperations, do you know of any? and if you don't, do you have an generalized algorithm I could implement on code? Thanks for your help, I am currently reading this paper, that may have the answer:
https://www.preprints.org/manuscript/201902.0176/v1/download

But anything that can help me do this faster is appreciated. I am willing to give you credit on the paper if you can help me do this faster haha. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are inverse hyperoperations? I have never encountered them before.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a math major, so the terminology might be off a little. I mean the opposite of tetration for example, as in the square root is the "inverse" of exponentiation.

Comment: If you can implement hyperoperations, then inverse hyperoperations is just solving an nonlinear equation and there are general algorithms for that.

Comment: For inverse tetration, i.e super logarithm, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85847/calculate-the-super-logarithm) and super root [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/calculate-the-super-root-of-a-number) might help

Comment: As with exponentiation there are two inverses (solving for the left/base or right/height). Tetration does not have a commonly accepted definition for non-integer heights, and higher hyperoperations does not have commonly accepted definitions for non-integer bases or heights. You should clarify which inverse(s) you want and how you intend on handling cases without commonly accepted definitions (e.g. how would you solve $2[4]x=3$).